# Combine Array Of Strings With String

Tags: javascript, ecmascript-6

I need to combine the **LAST** `fromAddress` and `toAddresses` values into just one set of array without duplication and without the `loginUser`.

Expected Output

```
   { "newResponse": ["james@gmail.com", "ken@yahoo.com"] }
```

```js
const loginUser = "jane@gmail.com"

const old = [
  {
    "toAddresses": ["joker@gmail.com", "jake@gmail.com"],
  },
  { 
    "fromAddress": "ken@yahoo.com",
    "toAddresses": ["jane@gmail.com", "james@gmail.com"],
  }
];

let emailLength = old?.length - 1
let email = old[emailLength]

 

const newResponse = Array.from(new Set([...email.map(x => [...x.toAddresses].concat([...x.fromAddress || []]))])) 
console.log(newResponse)
```

Comment: Do you really expect `newResponse` to have a `"newResponse"` property?

Comment: I think `[...x.fromAddress]` is going to give you the characters in the fromAddress since it's not in an array.

Comment: You expect to get an object, but use `Array.from` which returns an object? You attempt to `map` over `email`, which is an object - did you mean to map over `old`? You spread the `x.fromAddress` which is a string into an array of characters? You want a result "*without the `loginUser`*", but you're not even referencing that anywhere in your code? Please up your game and make a viable attempt that at least doesn't throw an error. If you have trouble because you don't know where to start, ask a specific question about what you are stuck at.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

```js
const loginUser = "jane@gmail.com"

const old = [
  {
    "toAddresses": ["joker@gmail.com", "jake@gmail.com"],
  },
  { 
    "fromAddress": "ken@yahoo.com",
    "toAddresses": ["jane@gmail.com", "james@gmail.com"],
  }
];

let last = old[old.length - 1];
let combined = new Set([last.fromAddress, ...last.toAddresses]);
combined.delete(loginUser);
let newResponse = Array.from(combined);
console.log({newResponse});
```

Answer (score -1):

You're trying to call `map` on an object, but is only an array method.

You can just access the properties directly on the `email` object, since you know what you're looking for you don't need to iterate on it.

Then filter the array for the logged in user and construct a new object for the response.

```js
const loginUser = "jane@gmail.com"

const old = [
  {
    "toAddresses": ["joker@gmail.com", "jake@gmail.com"],
  },
  { 
    "fromAddress": "ken@yahoo.com",
    "toAddresses": ["jane@gmail.com", "james@gmail.com"],
  }
];

let emailLength = old?.length - 1
let email = old[emailLength]



let addresses = Array.from(new Set([...email.toAddresses, email.fromAddress]))
addresses = addresses.filter(addy => addy !== loginUser)
const newResponse = { "newResponse": addresses }
console.log(newResponse)
```